# Bootstrap Datetimepicker no display empty

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

[Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) not functioning well no date time display. No display empty. What supposed to be the problem?

Including CSS and JS scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/user.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

datetimepicker

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: seems fine, can you check the developer console for any error message?

Comment: @Manwal. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gvbLn5ud/).  click on calendar icon. it will open calendar.@kucing_terbang is correct.

Comment: @Bluescript  your JS code correct. click on the calendar icon, if it doesn't open calendar, then plugin files are not loaded properly. open console and reload the page to see the errors

Comment: this error when  i open console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
picker.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-datepicker.js:335(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-datepicker.js:474
users.html:121 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ users.html:121m.Callbacks.j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2J @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and realized that `bootstrap-datetimepicker` depends on `bootstrap-glyphicons` to display the default UI.

Because I'm using font-awesome, I changed the call to `.datetimepicker` to:

```
$("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        today: "fas fa-bomb",
        date: "fas fa-calendar",
        time: "fas fa-clock-o",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        next: "fa fa-arrow-right",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down",
        previous: "fa fa-arrow-left",
        clear: "fas fa-circle-o",
        close: "fas fa-times"
    },
});
```

Documentation: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#icons

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are applying dateTimePicker on `Div` instead of input:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'> //here
```

Instead of this give id to your input and then apply to this, like:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="dateInput" />
$('#dateInput').datetimepicker();//this should be in js
```

Something like [**This Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zL9k1y66/)

Comment: still i got nothing empty textbox.

Comment: Have you checked with DEMO?

Comment: I have done check the demo still not working when i click the icon